# Save event change in WP Fullcalendar: editable + draggable

Tags: calendar, plugin-events-calendar, drag-drop

**Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullcalendar/**

I use a plugin to display my “custom_post_type” events.

1. I have modified the “wp-fullcalendar.php” plugin file in several places to show the start and end time of the “custom_fields” event.
2. I also edited the “inline.js” file in the “includes / js /” folder to make the calendar “editable” and “dragable”.
3. But I CAN’T set the calendar to save the change to my “custom_post_type” event when I make a change by moving the event on the calendar.

I read the documentation for the JS plugin “calendar.io”, but I can’t insert the code into the already finished plugin “WP Fullcalendar”.

Will you help please? Thanks!!!

**These are my edits to the plugin code**

***wp-fullcaleendar.php***

```
/*
$post_date = substr($post->post_date, 0, 10);
    $post_timestamp = strtotime($post->post_date);
    */
    $post_date = substr($post->_EventStartDate, 0, 10);
    $post_timestamp = strtotime($post->_EventStartDate);
    
    $post_end_date = substr($post->_EventEndDate, 0, 10);
    $post_end_timestamp = strtotime($post->_EventEndDate);
```

***include/js/inline.js***

```
editable: true,
droppable: true,
eventOverlap: true,
dayMaxEvents: true,
```

I need to save my appointment as soon as I drag its location on my calendar or when I change its duration. And I just can't do this. The source of the code, how to achieve this, is here:

**https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing**

Comment: Third-party plugins are out of scope here, but in general I would advise you not to edit plugins. As soon as a security update is applied, your changes are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @vancoder's advice on editing plugins. That being said, I think you might need to do two things:

1. Edit the JavaScript to use the eventDrop callback. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop
2. When the callback is fired, is there currently a method to update an event? I see in their documentation that you can allow users to create events, but I didn't see anything for editing. https://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/user-event-guest-submissions/.